# how to show multiple webviews/URL's under one UiViewController when the user clicks different cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiwebview

I have an app which has 12 cells in one `UICollectionView`. I want that when the user clicks on each of the cells it should open up the respective websites in one `WebView` like the first one should open facebook another one should open twitter etc..

The code to create the cells in the the `UICollectionView` is below i need to know how do i create an array may be of urls and pass it to all the cells to display the websites.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.category.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell1

    cell.imageopenview.image = self.imagearray[indexPath.row]

    cell.titlelabel .text = self.category[indexPath.row]


    return cell
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to keep an array of your URLs similar to how you have a `imagearray` and `categoryarray`. You will create these URLs in the same place you are making your categories and images, I suspect.

I also suggest you follow Swift camelCase naming conventions for variables (for example, `imageArray' and 'categoryArray').

Since each cell in your collection view is a distinct unit with an image, a category title, and a URL, it also makes sense to store a single array of structs rather than three separate arrays.

```
struct SocialMediaSite {
  var image: UIImage
  var title: String
  var URL: NSURL
}
```

If you do this, then in your view controller you can keep just a single array: `data: [SocialMediaSite]`. Make sure you set this array with the appropriate data in the same places you set your images and categories arrays. This is where you will need to also set the URLs for the websites you want each cell to correspond too. You create an NSURL using `NSURL(string: "http://www.somesite.com")` and store it in the `URL` variable.

Using a single data array, your function (following Swift naming conventions also) will look something like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell1

    cell.imageOpenView.image = data[indexPath.row].image
    cell.titleLabel .text = data[indexPath.row].title

    return cell
}
```

This will display your cells in the UICollectionView as you currently have things. Now, to load a request to a website in your UIWebView when you tap a cell, you must implement another of the `UICollectionViewDelegate` methods: `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)`. This is called whenever a user taps on a cell.

In this function, you might do something as follows:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCellData = data[indexPath.row]

    let url = selectedCellData.URL // This is the website you want to go to for the cell you just tapped
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url)) // Tell the webView to load this URL

    ...
}
```

You may also want to consider having your view controller become the delegate of the UIWebView if you want to perform any actions while the web page is loading or if there was an error loading the web page for that URL.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I will go ahead and try it out and update my post. I am a beginner so excuse my mistakes. Thnx for the help